# How to slide items in a ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, slideshow, qtquick2

I would like to create a slideshow showing 3 items with a picture and a label for each, the item in the middle being highlighted (picture is bigger and a description text appears below the label).

When a corresponding arrow is clicked, I would like the items to "slide" instead of just appearing where they should. Unfortunately, the `Behavior on x {
NumberAnimation{...}}` code in the delegate does not do this.

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: display
    width: 500
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Item {
        id: conteneur
        anchors.leftMargin: 50
        height: display.height / 1.2
        width: display.width / 1.2
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Rectangle {
            id: boutonAvant
            height: conteneur.height
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            width: 68
            x: -50
            color: "transparent"
            z: 1

            Text {
                id: pictureAv
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "<"
                font.pixelSize: 90
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: buttonAvMouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: listview.decrementCurrentIndex()
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: listview
            clip: true
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            width: conteneur.width
            height: conteneur.height / 1.2
            anchors.centerIn: conteneur
            model: myListModel
            delegate: myDelegate

            maximumFlickVelocity: 700
            snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem

            highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
            highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
            preferredHighlightBegin: conteneur.width * 0.3
            preferredHighlightEnd: conteneur.width * 0.3 + conteneur.width * 0.4

            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                positionViewAtIndex(currentIndex, ListView.SnapPosition)
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                currentIndex = 1
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: boutonApres
            height: conteneur.height
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            x: conteneur.width - 10
            width: 68
            color: "transparent"

            Text {
                id: pictureAp
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: ">"
                font.pixelSize: 90
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: buttonApMouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: listview.incrementCurrentIndex()
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: myListModel

        ListElement {
            name: "rectangle 0"
            desc: "blabla"
            mycolor: "green"
        }

        ListElement {
            name: "rectangle 1"
            desc: "blabla"
            mycolor: "blue"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "rectangle 2"
            desc: "blabla"
            mycolor: "lightblue"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "rectangle 3"
            desc: "blabla, \n with several lines for test \n and more lines \n and more lines"
            mycolor: "gold"
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: myDelegate

        Rectangle {
            id: cadre
            opacity: listview.currentIndex === index ? 1 : 0.5
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: listview.currentIndex === index ? 0 : 35
            width: listview.currentIndex === index ? listview.width * 0.4 : listview.width * 0.3
            height: conteneur.height
            border.color: mycolor
            color: "transparent"

            Behavior on x {
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 800
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example that runs? It looks like you've left out stuff, the formatting of your code is broken, and you're using images which we don't have access to.

Comment: I just added an example code

Comment: Thanks. I trimmed it down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` inherits `Flickable` which uses `contentX` and `contentY` to govern what's visible. The model `Rectangles` don't actually move.

I would try a `Behavior` on `ListView`'s `contentX`. Note that the documentation for `positionViewAtIndex` says not manipulate those directly because the math on them is not predictable – but a behavior on them may work.

Comment: Yes I thought about that too... and unfortunately it gave no result

Answer (score 0):

I finally had some result using this :

//In bouton Avant :

```
MouseArea{
  id: boutonAvant
  anchors.fill: parent
  hoverEnabled: true

  onClicked: {
  pictureAp.visible = true;
  var oldPos = listview.contentX;
  listview.decrementCurrentIndex();
  var newPos = oldPos - listview.width*0.3; // listview.width*0.3 is the width of one item that is not the current one

  if(listview.currentIndex == 0){
    pictureAv.visible = false;
  }

  anim.running = false
  anim.from = oldPos;
  anim.to = newPos;
  anim.running = true;
  }
 }
```

}

The ListView becomes :

```
 ListView{
            id: listview
            clip: true
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            width: conteneur.width
            height: conteneur.height/1.2
            anchors.centerIn: conteneur
            model: myListModel
            delegate: myDelegate

            Component.onCompleted: {
                currentIndex = 1;
            }

         }

  NumberAnimation { id: anim; target: listview; property: "contentX"; duration: 800 }
```

And boutonApres is similar to boutonAvant with :

```
        MouseArea{
            id: buttonApMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onClicked: {
                pictureAv.visible = true;

                var oldPos = listview.contentX;
                listview.incrementCurrentIndex();
                var newPos = oldPos + listview.width*0.3;

                if(listview.currentIndex == listview.count-1){
                    pictureAp.visible = false;
                }

                anim.running = false
                anim.from = oldPos;
                anim.to = newPos;
                anim.running = true;
           }
        }
```

It works fines when items being 'slided' are in the middle of the listview but when I get to the first item (on the last click on the left arrow), or to the last item (on the last click on the right arrow), I get a disturbing 'flick' as if the listview was trying to move at two places at the same time, following 2 different orders. But I can't see where this could come from...